# How can I get application side-menu on base Unity install?

Tags: unity, 11.04

Trying to make a very speedy Ubuntu install for my network, I installed the command-line version of Natty Narwhal and the following packages: xorg, gnome-base, unity

My .xinitrc is simply exec ck-launch-session gnome-session.  Unity appears to be working, though there's no side-menu like I'm using to seeing in UNE.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't switch Windows either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean [netbook-launcher-efl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/netbook-launcher-efl) and not Unity. Furthermore you are probably missing alt-tab because of missing mutter.

Comment: What's the difference between netbook-launcher-efl and unity?  After installing mutter, gnome, unity, and compiz, things work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: netbook-launcher-efl is basically the same as the previous (10.04) netbook experience, as opposed to unity, which does not have the side menu.

Comment: http://bit.ly/f3H8Ja This is without netbook-launcher-efl. I thought this was going to be the new interface for all versions.

Comment: Well, I just removed compiz and things still work.  Maybe I was just selecting the wrong gdm drop-down box for "Ubuntu Desktop"?!

Comment: compiz is not needed for the experience to work ;) (it does make it more awesome though)